# Angular Routing Components

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, routes

I currently have the following index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dentist Appointment System</title>
  <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>
  <app-component>
    loading...
  </app-component>
</body>
</html>
```

my app.component.html is:

```
<div class="main-container">
   <header class="header header-6">
      Dentists Appointment System
   </header>
   <nav>
      <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
      <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
      <a routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">Register</a>
   </nav>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
   {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
   {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
   {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
];

@NgModule({
             imports: [
                RouterModule.forRoot(
                      appRoutes,
                      {
                         useHash: true,
                         enableTracing: false // <-- debugging purposes only
                      }
                )
             ],
             exports: [
                RouterModule
             ]
          })
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

What i ultimately want to do is. Initially you go to Home page. On top you have register and login nav options. On click - they appear in router outlet. After you login or register I want to redirect each type of user to a different component like : DentistComponent, PatientComponent, AdminComponent and I want those components to replace not only whats in the router outlet, but also to replace the nav bar I have on top (with login, reg and home). And then in each user component I will have different child components and routes, ultimately different views.

I receive the currenlty logged in user type like so:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.userRole = CommonUtil.getSessionUserRole();
      console.log(this.userRole); //DENTIST, PATIENT, ADMIN
   }
```

so I have access to it in my app.component.ts..

What is the best way to using the userRole to open the different components (dentist, patient, admin) and replace the app-component's content with them? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use Children Paths like

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {path:'', component:MainComponent, children:[
       {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
       {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
       {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
   ]},
   {path:'Patient',component:PatienComponent,children:[
     {path:'...}
   ],
    {path:'Admin',component:AdminComponent,children:[..]},
    ...
   {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}

];
```

Comment: that sounds great, but how do I open patient/dentist/admin with the type check? should I use *ngIf and check if user type corresponds or what?

Comment: In your logging.service you use router.navigate to send to the correct path. You can use Route guards to restrict the navigatio (see https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards). *ngIf must be using if you want to hide/show a very short parts of your html